# How to save the complete URL called?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, logging

I want to be able to save the complete URL called to reach a page including all the parameters ?

```
    dim fs,f
     fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     f=fs.OpenTextFile("D:\www\log.txt", 8, True)
    f.WriteLine(" ")


    f.WriteLine(" ")
    f.Write(" : ")
    f.Write(" : ")
    f.Write(Request.QueryString("type"))
```

I believe the above code will store one of the parameters. However i want to be able to capture the complete URL?

f.Write(Context.Request.Url.Host)

only gets me the first part?

Comment: There's no reason with asp.net to _ever_ use Server.CreateObject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

Answer (score 1):

Try `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

The [AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) property includes the entire URI stored in the Uri instance, including all fragments and query strings